# How Does SPFx React to a button being pressed?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Does anyone know how the SharePoint Framework reacts to a button being pressed ?

What TypeScript do I need to make this happen (ie get notified when a button has been pressed)?

Regards

Nigel

Comment: Which JavaScript framework are you using? You can find samples how to do it in React, Angular and without any framework in the sample Web Parts available at https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/90335743b0a7daf3192a1f519dda1cafd5edb6a1/samples/sharepoint-crud/src/webparts.

Comment: @WaldekMastykarz-MVP Its a very useful link, thanks for sharing

Comment: Yes - I got the link from @VesaJuvenon .  It was very useful.